# non-svg D3 tooltip not updating when dragging

Tags: javascript, d3.js, draggable

I'm trying to write a "draggable" d3 tooltip using a div element instead of svg elements.
This is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/emepyc/LDpdz/4/

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
.on("drag", function(d) {
    console.log(this);
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);
    console.log(coords);
    d3.select(this)
        .style("right", coords[0])
        .style("left", coords[0])
        .style("top", coords[1])
    .call(function(){console.log(coords)});
});

var div = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "kk")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("left", "100px")
    .style("top", "50px")
    .call(drag);

div
    .append("table")
    .append("th")
    .text("Hello world");
```

I'm very puzzled because although the callback is called on dragging, the style elements are not updated in the div element.
Any idea what is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem is that you're setting the `left` and `top` attributes of the `div` as numbers. This works fine in SVG, but HTML really expects a unit with the numbers as well. Just append `+ "px"` to the end of those settings and it'll work fine.

There are a few other things though. You should set the [origin of the drag](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-origin) because otherwise you'll notice a jump when you start dragging the element. I've implemented this and a few other simplifications [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LDpdz/5/).

Comment: Arrgh... Yes, I needed a bit of sleeping. Thanks a lot for the other tips as well!

Answer (score 1):

CSS is a bit unforgiving when it comes to values without dimensions.

The fix is adding the `px` dimension:

```js
d3.select(this)
    .style("left", coords[0] + 'px')
    .style("top", coords[1] + 'px')
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/sz6JC/)

I have also changed the `parent` to be the `body` instead of the `this`. You might want to look at `event.dx` and `event.dy` to make the movements relative instead of absolute.